# How to align the table cells content on the top?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table. Each cell has content of different length.

For this reason, the content is not aligned on the top.

I would like the first lines be aligned also in cells with few lines of text (the content should always start from the top).

Instead the content is vertically centered in the middle.

How can I fix this (a cross-browser solution.. working in I.E. as well)

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

in css

```
td, th {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

use valign="top" on the td

```
<td valign="top">....</td>
```

setting the attribute on the tr should work for the entire row like wise for table

Comment: This is a pure html solution